# Subclassing Tkinter.Tcl

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, subclassing

I would like to extend the behavior of Tkinter.Tcl. I tried subclassing it but it turns out Tcl is a factory function that returns an object. If Tcl were a class, I would simply:

```
from Tkinter import *
class TclPlus(Tcl): # <- broken
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
       print "foo"
```

I could sublcass Tk and my new class would have a Tcl factory function, but I'd be back where I started. Also, Tk includes all the windowing overhead and I don't need that.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Edit: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52295-automatic-delegation-as-an-alternative-to-inherita/ This appears to be exactly what I'm after. Comments?

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside `Tcl` function, you can see an interesting flag used to create `Tk` instance

```
def Tcl(screenName=None, baseName=None, className='Tk', useTk=0):
    return Tk(screenName, baseName, className, useTk)
```

Thus you can subclass `Tk` and inhibit Tk instantiation

```
class TclPlus(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self,useTk=0)


tcl = TclPlus()
tcl.eval("expr 6*7")
```

Comment: Yes. I found that and am just now getting around to updating this question. Thanks. My OS has _tkinter.so packaged separately. I was looking for the python source in that package despite reading multiple times that Tkinter is part of python since way back.